Upload ESP32 Cam photo to PHP
I want to store captured images to my php website, I am using the following code and I have tried different variations and solutions nothing seems to work I have also looked over the internet for over 3 days looking for a solution and I found nothing.
How can I upload captured photos to a php website?


import urequests
import camera
from machine import Pin
import network
import urequests
import machine
import time

machine.freq(240000000)
sta_if = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
sta_if.active(True)
time.sleep(1)
if sta_if.isconnected():
    sta_if.disconnect()
    print (f'started in the connected state, but now disconnected')
    time.sleep(1)
    sta_if.connect('dlink-M961-2.4G-a176', 'skmfu47667')
    time.sleep(1)
    print(sta_if.isconnected())
else:
    print (f'started in the disconnected state')
    print(sta_if.active())
    sta_if.connect('dlink-M961-2.4G-a176', 'skmfu47667')
    print(sta_if.isconnected())

gc.collect()
gc.mem_free()


flash = Pin(4, Pin.OUT)
time.sleep(1)
camera.init(0, format=camera.JPEG, fb_location=camera.PSRAM)
time.sleep(1)
camera.quality(12)
camera.framesize(9)
flash.value(1)
time.sleep(1)

gc.collect()
gc.mem_free()

buf = camera.capture()

flash.value(0)
file = open("/esp32-1.jpg","wb")
file.write(buf)
file.close()

file = open("/esp32-1.jpg","rb")

r = urequests.request("POST", "https://x.x.net/python/image.php", json={"name":"esp32.jpg","photo":file})
print(r.text)


"I have tried different variations and solutions nothing seems to work" - please understand that it's important to explain in detail which part of your code fails and how exactly. Otherwise we can't help you.

The standard APIs for file uploading in HTTP uses the multipart/form-data content type.
Here is an answer for how to do that in MicroPython: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62424855/1967571
